# Run sudo commands from inside of docker compose

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, sudo, strongbox

I am using **AWS EC2 instance** and have installed **docker** and **docker-compose** on AWS linux.

Now I have a **docker-compose.yml** file which is trying the command `mkdir -p /workspace/.m2/repositories`. Now this command requires **sudo**, otherwise it gives permissions error.

I tried adding **sudo** inside **docker-compose** but it gave me an error saying

> sudo: command not found

I can run this command manually and can comment this command inside of `docker-compose.yml` file but I am interested to know that is there any way to run this command from inside of `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Install sudo in the container.

Comment: I am using docker-compose. So I assume I need to write install sudo command inside docker-compose.yml file. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @YugSingh - I think your sudo command should be in `Dockerfile` as alluded to by tkausl

Comment: What do you mean, 'sudo inside docker-compose'? docker-compose is just a wrapper around docker cli, it doesn't do anything else, u can run something inside docker container, e.g. docker file

Comment: @ScottSkiles I have pulled a github repo and it contains only docker-compose.yml and no dockerfile is there

Comment: because docker compose stores link to images and surrounding info, e.g. networks, volumes and everything else. all logic stores inside docker image

Comment: u need to execute docker-compose up -d to run docker container with info described in this docker-compose file.

Comment: Can you run `sudo docker-compose up`? When you verify this works you can run `sudo docker-compose up -d` to run it detached.

Comment: @ScottSkiles I can run `docker-compose up` and it's working fine. Then it is trying to run mkdir inside container and it's saying sudo doesn't exist. I was thinking that it has something to do with the host machine but as mentioned by @Dmitri that docker compose is just a wrapper around docker-cli I think compose is failing to run sudo insid ethe container. Also I tried running docer-compose up -d but the contaienr stopped in few seconds

Comment: And what about `sudo docker-compose up`? Have you attempted to use that command yet with sudo in ec2? Do you have sudo permissions on the EC2 instance? You do not run `sudo` from inside `docker-compose`. You run `sudo` from the ec2 instance. If this does not work, then you're spot on, you need to fix `sudo` in the container. Can you link the origin of the `docker-compose.yml ` file?

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files? If your are doing `mkdir` in a `root` owned area of the filesystem on startup, and the user in the container is not `root` - then you should probably back up and do this in the `Dockerfile` - there you can change user with the `USER` instruction.

Comment: @ScottSkiles yes I am following this link https://strongbox.github.io/developer-guide/building-the-code-with-docker.html

Comment: @AndreasLorenzen pls find the link in above comment

Comment: when i do docker-compose up I am getting the error. Now I was able to start the container manually and when inside the container I tried the mkdir command the user didn't have the permissions and sudo didn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may have a solution for you. You can extend the `strongbox` image in a custom `Dockerfile` to solve this issue I think.

Create a new `Dockerfile`, like this one:

**`Dockerfile`**

```
FROM strongboxci/alpine:jdk8-mvn-3.5

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /workspace/.m2/repositories
RUN chown jenkins:jenkins /workspace/.m2/repositories

USER jenkins
```

Then build the image with something like this:

```sh
docker build -t mystrongbox:01 .
```

And finally update the `docker-compose.yml` file to this:

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
version: '2'
services:
  strongbox-from-web-core:
    image: mystrongbox:01
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
         echo ""
         echo "[NOTICE]   This will take at least 2 to 5 minutes to start depending on your machine and connection!"
         echo ""
         echo "           Open http://localhost:48080/storages to browse the repository contents."
         echo ""
         sleep 5
         mkdir -p /workspace/.m2/repositories
         mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=/workspace/.m2/repositories
         cd strongbox-web-core
         mvn spring-boot:run -Dmaven.repo.local=/workspace/.m2/repositories
    ports:
      - 48080:48080
    volumes:
      - ./:/workspace
    working_dir: /workspace
```

Finally try again with:

```sh
docker-compose up
```

Then you will have the directory created in the image already, and ownership set to the `jenkins` user.

Comment: Please let me know if there is something else that I can do to help, or perhaps accept the answer if it was useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the developers at [strongbox/strongbox](https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox). We're thrilled that someone is trying out our Docker images for development :)

> Now this command requires sudo, otherwise it gives permissions error.

What you are experiencing, is likely a permission issue. Our Docker images are running as `user.group = 1000.1000` (which is usually the first user on many distributions). I suspect that your UID/GID is different, which you can check by doing `id -u` and `id -g`. If it's something other than `1000.1000` - you would need to do a workaround:

1. Create a user & group with IDs `1000.1000`:

   ```
   groupadd -g 1000 jenkins
   useradd -u 1000 -g 1000 -s /bin/bash -m jenkins
   ```
2. Chown/chmod the cloned strongbox project like this:

   ```
   chown -R `id -u`.1001 /path/to/strongbox-project
   chmod -R 775 /path/to/strongbox-project
   ```
3. Try again `docker-compose up`

This image does not have `sudo` installed, so you wouldn't be able to execute it. However, you shouldn't need it as well, because the `/workspace` is being mounted from your FS (this is the strongbox project) and it will write `/workspace/.m2/repository` in the volume.